# Смещение координат при масштабировании элемента с помощью CSS

Tags: javascript, css, width, координаты

CSS

```
#canvas{max-width:100%;max-height:100%;}
```

При масштабировании получаю не правильные координаты (offsetX ,offsetY).Холст размером 1920/1080 ,а получаемые координаты разнятся от ширины экрана .На изображении чёрный круг - полученные координаты ,а нарисованный красный крестик - фактическое местоположение курсора .

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение : координата * (нужная ширина / canvas.clientWidth или clientHeight) .Также работает и в полноэкранном режиме ,перезагружаться не надо .